# Unpermitted parameter: student_ids in a nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble with saving Classroom_Students. The form recognizes the correct parameters, they just won't save to the database. I know similar questions have been asked, but none of the answers (that I've seen) have solved my problem.

Error Message:

> Unpermitted parameter: student_ids

I am trying to add students to a classroom through the classroom_students table

//Classroom.rb

```
has_many :classroom_students
  has_many :students, through: :classroom_students
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :classroom_students
```

//Student.rb

has_many :classroom_students
has_many :classrooms, through: :classroom_students

//ClassroomStudent.rb (join table)

```
 belongs_to :classroom
    belongs_to :student
```

//Classroom Controller

```
def classroom_params
    params.require(:classroom).permit(:name, :description, :teacher_id, 
    classroom_student_attributes:[:student_ids => []])
  end
```

By the way, all other attributes are saving into the database with the classroom.

//Form to create a classroom

```
<%= simple_form_for @classroom do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :classroom_students do |classroom_students| %>
      <%= f.association :students, as: :check_boxes %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

All student names display and when a form is submitted it is read under a classroom.

```
Parameters: {"utt8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jklqjwerqjfeiqwjrkljfa231=", "classroom"=>{"name"=>"Not Violin Class", "description"=>"It's not", "student_ids"=>["1", "3", ""]}, "commit"=>"Create Classroom"}
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 9]]
Unpermitted parameter: student_ids
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "classrooms" ("name", "description", "teacher_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Not Violin Class"], ["description", "Please Please Please"], ["teacher_id", 9]]
   (11.2ms)  commit transaction
```

Any feedback would be appreciated, I haven't been able to figure this out yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unpermitted parameter: student_ids

You are sending `student_ids` in the `classromm` hash, you need to send it in the `classroom_students` hash

Change this

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :classroom_students do |classroom_students| %>
  <%= f.association :students, as: :check_boxes %>
<% end %>
```

to

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :classroom_students do |classroom_students| %>
  <%= classroom_students.association :students, as: :check_boxes %>
<% end %>
```

Also, `classroom_student_attributes` should be `classroom_students_attributes`

```
def classroom_params
  params.require(:classroom).permit(:name, :description, :teacher_id, classroom_students_attributes: [:student_ids => []])
end
```

***Update:***

> Association :students not found

This is because the association on `classroom_student` is `belongs_to :student`, so this line

```
<%= classroom_students.association :students, as: :check_boxes %>
```

should be

```
<%= classroom_students.association :student, as: :check_boxes %>
```

Comment: @MaxLeoTony Try changing `:students` to `:student` in the checkbox input